# CopyLocal not working if assembly is in GAC

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm having an issue where even though copylocal is set to true for dependency projects, Visual Studio wants to rebuild everything because output dlls are not being copied to the bin directories of the projects that are dependent on them.

When I go to build, msbuild detects that the reference assembly is not in the output folder of the current project it's checking to see if it's up to date, and then builds it, I believe just using the GAC dll without ever copying it. It seems like there's a disconnect between the detection of the file in the output, and the one it actually decides to use.

If I delete the dependent assemblies from the GAC, the copy works normally and everything stops rebuilding constantly. If I also toggle the CopyLocal property and allow the `<private>true</private>` tag to be added to the .csproj file for the suspect references, it solves my issues as well.

The problem is these projects are not a part of my team and we don't want to modify them. My team members also have identical dev machines with identical software and this issue doesn't occur for them. The other problem is some of the software that our product is dependent on automatically installs the assemblies to the GAC when they are run, so I can't just keep it deleted.

Has anyone experienced this and have any insight as to why this is occurring?

Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, .net 4.6.1

Comment: Side note: why you are trying to copy local if assemblies will be installed in the GAC anyway?

Comment: I assume because the referenced projects are built as a part of our product, and are continually being maintained by other teams as well so we need to make sure we always have the most recent version. I'm relatively new software developer at the professional level so I'm not going to pretend I know for sure, but I believe that's why.

Comment: You should already have a copy of the assemblies that are in the GAC so you can use it as a reference assembly for the original project.  You can force Copy Local to True to get MSBuild to make a copy, even though it is already in the GAC.  But that has a knack for getting set back to False when you reload the project.  Simplest way is to just punt the problem, you *know* the project has a dependency on the GACed assembly.  So just add it.

Comment: CopyLocal is not set to false though for the references. It shows at true in Visual Studio, but the `<private>true</private>` tag isn't in the .csproj at all, which I believe means it defaults to true. If I add a reference to the GACd assembly that involves modifying the source of projects I can't touch, like adding the previously mentioned tag to the .csproj file. That's sort of the crux of the issue :/